# Mediawiki citation/footnote capability in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Wikis?

Tags: wiki, footnote

We're migrating a Mediawiki installation to SharePoint 2010. We've examined and dealt with all of the issues of lost/different functionality successfully with the exception of how to deal with the `<ref>` tags in Mediawiki.

Has anyone come up with a way to implement such in an SP2010 Enterprise Wiki? We don't need to do it exactly the same way, but we do need some sort of way for users to create footnotes in an article.

I was hoping to find a 3rd party piece that I could just buy but so far I haven't found anything. Ideas welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only method would be to go into the HTML source of the wiki article and create an anchor tag to point to an ID further down on the page.  I was hoping for more robust wiki capabilities after having some discussions with the wiki product manager in the past.  It's still far from an enterprise worthy wiki :-(